# JavaScript - Timing Issue - How to wait on Request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Image that needs to be displayed based on the outcome of the AJAX Call. I don't load the jQuery and other Libraries like Foundation which is responsible for loading responsible image based on the device.

The response time of the AJAX call ranges from 800-1000 ms. If the response takes more than 1000 ms I would display a default image. Also I should send the AJAX request as the first request on load , hence it is set immediately as the first child of header.
[JSFiddle for Timing issue](https://jsfiddle.net/jhL4vzus/1/)

```
<html><head><script>set Timeout of 1000 ms .....xhr.send();</script>
<body>
  <div id="id_in_response" style="display:none"><img src="xyz"></div>
  <div id="default_on_timeout" style="display:none"><img src="xyz"></div>
....Loads of Elements.....
<footer>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="foundation.js"></script>
  <script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
```

Explanation of custom js : 
Custom js will execute a Foundation library js to load the responsive image.

The problem is how should the XHR communicate with custom.js function that there is either a TIMEOUT OR Response has to be processed. I cannot use jQuery Promise because the jQuery will load after the HTML is downloaded. I cannot use Native Promises yet .
It can be that while the XHR response comes in , but the custom.js has still not loaded or getting parsed. I also cannot assume that resonse time will be always be in the range of 800-1000 ms. It can even come down to 300 ms or less.

Custome JS code :

```
$(document).foundation({interchange : named_queries {....}}); 

 // This will parse all the image tags , Run media Query and attach an 
 appropriate source to the image
```

Final Solution : [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/5rrck7o2/17/)

Comment: `I cannot use Promise because the jQuery will load after the HTML` that makes no sense ... Promise has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: should i use setInterval - wouldnt that block the page ?

Comment: @JaromandaX: Perhaps he/she is talking about jQuery's `$.Deferred` rather than native promises.

Comment: Don't use a timer. That's still no guarantee the request completed, especially if the user is on a slow connection. I'm sure there must be some callback/promise pattern which you can use here.

Comment: @JaromandaX - yes I am talking about jquery Deferred. I cannot use ECMA Script 6 promises

Comment: Promises are the correct way. You could use a dedicated promise library in your `head` to be able to use promises without having jQuery loaded. Another way *could* be an interval to check periodically, but that's **not** good. It's possible, but can slow down your browser significantly if these intervals pile up.

Comment: `I cannot use ECMA Script 6 promises` OK, don't see why not, since Promises can be polyfilled in about 3k of code - still, no problem when not using Promises, this can be done easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

poor mans "future" code

```
var specialRequest = (function() {
    var cb;
    var cberr;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var doCallback = function(err) {
        if (cb === undefined) {
            cb = true;
            cberr = err;
        } else if (typeof cb === 'function') {
            cb(err, xhr);
        }
    };
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        xhr.abort(); //??
        doCallback('timeout');
    }, 1000);
    xhr.open('GET', 'whatever/your/url/is');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        doCallback(null);
    }
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        doCallback('error');
    }
    xhr.onloadend = function() {
        // if the XHR finishes before the setTimeout, cancel it
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    xhr.send();

    return function(callback) {
        if (cb === undefined) {
            cb = callback;
        } else if (cberr !== null) {
            callback(cberr, xhr);
        }
    }
})();
```

and then, in custom.js

```
specialRequest(function(error, xhr) {
    if (error) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        // handle success
    }
});
```

compare this with Promise code

```
var myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        reject(new Error('timeout'));
    }, 1000);
    xhr.open('GET', 'whatever/your/url/is');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(xhr);
    }
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        reject(new Error('error'));
    }
    xhr.send();
});
```

// in custom.js

```
myPromise.then(function(xhr) {
    // handle success
}).catch(function(reason) {
    // handle failure
});
```

Comment: I still cannot use this - onload should execute my foundation code which is in custom.js . How will it do. It might be that custom.js is still loading ..

Comment: right ... can you change `custom.js` at all? This is where Promises make this sort of thing a walk in the park :p

Comment: Ah. xhr.onreadystatechange - i can write this in my custom js .. and that works fine

Comment: well, it'd be xhr.onload/onerror/onloadend if you want to code in the 21st century :p

Comment: But do you think this is a serious downVote question  ?

Comment: Actually it doesnt work fine - if i write the xhr.onreadyState in custom js - it fails meaning the function for readyState is not called at all ..  if response comes too early i.e. 100 ms .. so i guess polyfill Promises is the best solution

Comment: Nope Jaromanda X - i was asking your opinion only . no offence

Comment: There is a way without promises. But promises make life easier

Comment: @user1428716 - I've edited with a proposed non-promise alternative

Comment: created jsFiddle to emulate the issue https://jsfiddle.net/jhL4vzus/1/ - Console please ..

Comment: `created jsFiddle to emulate the issue` - right, so you didn't use any of the code in the answer I updated 18 hours ago - neither the poor mans future nor the Promise code ... note, both would require editing the "custom.js" - so, can't update your fiddle

Comment: I will be doing it .. I created fiddle not in a ziffy.. I created github branch .. ghub client download.. finding a way to emulate ..went through Steve Souders blog..i appreciate your answer... And through promises will try Sir

Comment: Something's can be fast for you ...but may be  not for others
..;)

Comment: OK, I just thought it was interesting you posted the link to the fiddle in my answer, rather than in your question (where that code should've been)

Comment: updated the jsFiddle - for large time to load custom.js https://jsfiddle.net/jhL4vzus/28/

Answer (score 0):

> should i use setInterval - wouldnt that block the page ?

No, it wouldn't; but you'd use `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`, to establish your 1000ms timeout. E.g., **roughly**:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    // Use default image instead
}, 1000);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(/*...*/);
xhr.send(/*...*/);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        if (/*...you haven't already used the default image...*/) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            // Use the appropriate image...
        }
    }
};
```

Note that the above doesn't hold up the display of the page, which I strongly recommend **not** doing. Just fill in the image when you know what image to fill in (as above).

Comment: Ah. xhr.onreadystatechange - i can write this in my custom js .. and that works fine

Comment: Actually it doesnt work fine - if i write the xhr.onreadyState in custom js - it fails if response comes too early i.e. 100 ms .. so i guess polyfill Promises is the best solution

Comment: @user1428716: "it fails" doesn't tell us much, nor would promises be useful here. It sounds like you're having trouble with something that wasn't described in the question. I suggest sticking with it, debugging the failure, and if you still can't work it out, posting a new question with a [mcve] demonstrating the failure. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Crowler - The custom js if it loads after the readyState==4 has been hit .. it will not bind the onreadystatechange function ..sometimes custom js will load before the readyState==4 and then the binding happens successfully

Comment: @user1428716: None of which is in your question. The above works within the confines of the question asked. Again:  I suggest sticking with it, debugging the failure, and if you still can't work it out, posting a new question with a [mcve] demonstrating the failure. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Crowder - Created the jsFiddle - hope it helps